# C++ Print to file Bug: Reporting each time step error?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to store my c++ program results to text file but I only get the last command stored. Please help me out anyone. I was able to get the output on a textfile but not the whole step results for every execution.

```
int main()
{

    //File write name setting from the fstream dirrectory
    fstream file;
    file.open("Pressure.txt", ios::out);


    double length;
    double Dx;
    double Pl;
    double pr;
    double px;
    double NumberOfGrids;

    std::cout << "Enter the length of Slab: ";
    std::cin >> length;

    std::cout << "\nEnter the grid size: ";
    std::cin >> Dx;

    NumberOfGrids = length / Dx;
    std::cout << "\nTotal number of grids: " << NumberOfGrids << "\t";

    std::cout << "\nEnter the Pressure at length (L): ";
    std::cin >> Pl;

    std::cout << "\nEnter the Reservoir Pressure: ";
    std::cin >> pr;  

    do
    {
        px = Pl + ((pr - Pl)* (0.5*(Dx*NumberOfGrids / length)));
        --NumberOfGrids;
        std::cout << px << "\t\t";
        file << "Pressure along the Core Length " << endl << px << "\t\t";
        file.close();
    } while (NumberOfGrids >= 0);
```

Comment: You close file after writing each command. Move `file.close()` outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, that you close the file inside the loop. So the first iteration will go fine, after that `file` will not be an opened file anymore and thus invalid.

You should do this instead:

```
do
{
    px = Pl + ((pr - Pl)* (0.5*(Dx*NumberOfGrids / length)));
    --NumberOfGrids;
    std::cout << px << "\t\t";
    file << "Pressure along the Core Length " << endl << px << "\t\t";
    // Do not close file here!
} while (NumberOfGrids >= 0);
file.close(); // close it here instead!
```

Then your code should run fine.